# Exporting specific symbols using cmake

Tags: cmake

When building a shared library, it is possible to export specific symbols on Windows. I know that there is the `windows_export_all_symbols` option, but I don't necessarily want to export all of the symbols, just some of them. In addition, I do not want to modify source files.

Comment: Create `.def` file which lists symbols needed to be exported, and pass it to the `add_library()` call.

Comment: Or mark everything you want to export with `__declspec(dllexport)`. CMake even has a module to simplify this, `GenerateExportHeader`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way, taken from the Steinberg VST3 SDK:

```
if (WIN32)
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(ARAVST3TestPlugIn PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS /EXPORT:GetPluginFactory)
endif (WIN32)
```

This just adds the /EXPORT flag to the MSVC linker; I needed to export GetPluginFactory in this case.